# Detect mobile users in .Net Blazor Server project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Let me start of with saying that this is for statistics use so it doesn't have to be 100%.
I would like to detect mobile users in a Blazor Server project, since it is a signalR connection I cant use Request. I know that I could use js/jquery, but I would like to solve this without js/jquery.

Comment: Found the solution! Inject        var ngt = _HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ToList();
        var agent = ngt[8];

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution!

```cs
@Inject IHttpContextAccessor _HttpContextAccessor
var headers = _HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ToList();
var agent = headers [8];
```

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Your answer does not explain how to detect if it is a mobile device, headers[8] says if it is windows or other SO but I can't see nothing about mobile..